# Who walked in during Angela's meeting with her advisor in Malevolent?

Tags: ghost, malevolent

In the 2018 film, *[Malevolent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malevolent_(2018_film))*, one of the early incidents that Angela has showing that her medium abilities are coming out happens during a meeting with her academic advisor. She gets her prior indicators of paranormal activity, a nosebleed and a high ringing in her ears while the door handle starts jiggling and then a humanoid shape, looking to me like someone in a long coat, walks in. We then cut to another scene, and the incident isn't mentioned again.

Was there an intended identity to this person walking in? A deleted scene? Some insight from the book this was based on, *[Hush](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/27420636-hush)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parallel scene in *Hush* has Angela seeing a dead businessman through a window during her interview at Starbucks. It has the same setup where someone is talking to her, she has an increased ringing in her ears, and then suffers a nosebleed before having to leave the room, so it seems likely that the intent was the same here, that she saw a dead person that she had no particular connection to. Absent some additional clarification by the director of the film (I [left a tweet](https://twitter.com/FuzzyDugganSC/status/1247483763120132096?s=20), but received no response), I think this is the answer we have.

> “Um, well. I’m friendly,” I say. A sharp pain shoots through my temples. “I love coffee…” My right ear goes silent, and then a faint ringing echoes through that ear. I wince.
>
> *Not now*, I think. *Please, not here.* I try to keep smiling. The ringing moves to my left ear. It’s low and steady. “I…I’ve always gotten along with everyone. Except my brother.” Forcing a nervous laugh, I try to concentrate as the ringing grows. *Stay calm*, I think. *Stay calm*.
>
> In the distance, over Sam’s shoulder, I notice a businessman in a faded suit. He limps towards us from the other side of the glass window. Pressure builds behind my eyes. The businessman looks like he’s walking through quicksand. I brush my hands over my face, forcing myself to focus. “I…work well in…”
>
> Each step the businessman takes causes the ringing in my head to grow louder. I’m still talking to Sam, but I can’t hear my own voice. My throat constricts, the ringing taking over. Sam appears to be following along, but there’s now a puzzled expression on his face. *Can’t breathe. Can’t breathe.*
>
> The businessman halts behind Sam. Slowly, he peers into the window. His face is gaunt. Mouth agape. When his bloodshot eyes find mind, bile rises in my throat. I am officially going crazy. Either that or this man is officially dead. Both scenarios are not good.
>
> Sam must agree with me, because he suddenly stops smiling. His eyes widen. “Um,” he says, motioning to my nose. “You’ve got a…”
>
> I feel a soft dribble below my nostril and bring a hand to my face. A streak of blood smears my fingers.
>
> “Excuse me,” I say.